# How to append `?token=...` to the redirect URL when fetch API got 302?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

As title. I'm very new to this topic so I will use the example to describe what I want to achieve:

1. I'm browsing a Git-pages website with some images there. When I clicked those images, I found that the URL is appended with `?token=DSKLFJOS...`.
2. Now if I only copy the URL without this token, then I will get 404 as a response.
3. I found that the 404 is actually the second request. The first request is 302 and the token can be found from the response.
4. So, what I want to achieve is that I want to use `fetch` API to try to get the token from 302, and append it to the URL of the (redirect) request `?token=...` so that the second request will get 200.

My thought: Maybe this can be achieved after I learn more about the `credentials` and/or `redirect` options of the `fetch` API. But I'm not sure on this!

This is the current code that will fail with 404(on the second request). It is not written by me, so I don't understand it. (and sorry that I cannot post the full code since it's a private content)

```
    fetch(filePath)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => callback(arrayBuffer, arrayBuffer.byteLength));
```

Thanks for your reading. If I any of my idea is incorrect please feel free to correct me and post it as an answer!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Tell it to follow it `fetch(url, { method: 'GET', redirect: "follow" });`

Comment: @epascarello: Would that bring the `?token` automatically? I got 404 if no `?token` is provided in the URL.

Comment: @epascarello I just searched a little bit but it seems that `redirect: "follow"` is the default value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work. Basically, you just check the status code, and if it's 302 you will re-fetch the response with the token, then if the status is still greater than 300 you return null, if not you return the JSON response.

```js
async function getImage(url, token) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  
  // You can also say if (response.status >= 300 && response.status < 400)
  if (response.status === 302) {
    response = await fetch(`${url}?token=${token}`);
  }
  
  if (response.status >= 300) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return response.json();
}
```

Whit the headers location would be something like this:

```js
async function getImage(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  
  if (response.status === 302) {
    response = await fetch(`${url}?token=${response.headers.get('location')}`);
  }
  
  return response.json();
}
```

I remove the second if just to simplify the answer and just having in mind the request would be successful.

Comment: Now my following question about your code is how could I get the `token`?

Comment: Do you have an API where to get the token or does your app manage tokens in the cookies or in the localStorage?

Comment: Wow, I just found that the first 302 request's response header already has a field `location` which has token appended for me already.

Comment: Given this observation, it is possible to simplify your answer?

Comment: I just edited the answer so you can see if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make another request with the new URL with `fetch(originalResponse.url + token)`.

> The `url` read-only property of the Response interface contains the URL of the response. **The value of the `url` property will be the final URL obtained after any redirects.**

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url

Here's an example:

```js
let token = "abcdef"
fetch("page-that-redirects.com/")
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 404) {
      fetch(response.url + "?token=" + token)
        .then(/* do something */)
    }
  })

// Or with async/await:
let response = await fetch("page-that-redirects.com/")
if (response.status === 404) {
  let newResponse = await fetch(response.url + "?token=" + token)
  /* do something */
}
```

Comment: Could you create a sample scenario with how you will write the code? Sorry, I'm really new to this topic. I seems to understand what you mean but I'm not sure without code.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Now my following question about your code is how could I get the `token`?